Add custom metric in jobmanager
When I start the Flink JobManager, I see some standard metrics such as flink_jobmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesLoaded, flink_jobmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_TotalCapacity, etc.
I would like to add a custom metric to this list. In my case, I want to check a certain endpoint for availability or unavailability (up or down).
The documentation suggests creating a custom function to define the metric. However, in my case, the task is not available at the time when the job manager starts, so I want to extend the standard list of metrics with the availability of the job manager start.
How can this be done? Perhaps through a plugin or another approach?

I don't believe there's any provision for adding custom job manager metrics. Only operator-level metrics.
